# Background fetch and refresh completed after viewDidLoad in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-fetch

I'm trying to implement background fetch as well as refresh in iOS 10. 
I'm using XML parsing to parse the data and then storing it in a file in the document's directory. For parsing XML I'm using a custom class (XMLParser) that confirms the *NSXMLParserDelegate* protocol.

The background fetch works fine. But I'm having problems in displaying the refreshed data, both when I click on the refresh button as well as in viewDidLoad.

I'm calling the ***refreshData*** method in viewDidLoad. 
Here's how far I've gotten.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
//--Set background fetch--//
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
}
...
#pragma mark Background data fetch methods
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

NSDate *fetchStart = [NSDate date];

ArtsViewController *artsViewController = (ArtsViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

[artsViewController fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
    completionHandler(result);

    NSDate *fetchEnd = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = [fetchEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:fetchStart];
    NSLog(@"Background Fetch Duration: %f seconds", timeElapsed);

}];
}
```

ArtsViewController.h

```
@interface ArtsViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
@property BOOL newsAvailable;

-(void)fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler; // No problems here

@end
```

ArtsViewcontroller.m

```
@interface ArtsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrNewsData;


-(void)refreshData;
-(void)performNewFetchedDataActionsWithDataArray:(NSArray *)dataArray;

@end
...
@implementation ArtsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self refreshData];
//--Load the file that saves news--//
[self loadNews];
if (_newsAvailable == YES)
{

    [self setupPageViewController];
}
else
{
    [self showNoNewsMessage];
}
}
...
#pragma mark Data Fetch methods

-(void)refreshData{
XMLParser *xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithXMLURLString:ArtsNewsFeed];
[xmlParser startParsingWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *dataArray, NSError *error) {

        if (success) {
        [self performNewFetchedDataActionsWithDataArray:dataArray];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
}

-(void)performNewFetchedDataActionsWithDataArray:(NSArray *)dataArray{
// 1. Initialize the arrNewsData array with the parsed data array.
if (self.arrNewsData != nil) {
    self.arrNewsData = nil;
}
self.arrNewsData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:dataArray];


// 2. Write the file and reload the view.
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * newsFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arts2"]]; // NewsFile

if (![self.arrNewsData writeToFile:newsFilePath atomically:YES]) {
    _newsAvailable = NO;
    NSLog(@"Couldn't save data.");
}
else
{
    _newsAvailable = YES;
    NSLog(@"Saved data.");
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];

}
}
-(void)fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
XMLParser *xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithXMLURLString:ArtsNewsFeed];
[xmlParser startParsingWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *dataArray, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        NSDictionary *latestDataDict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *latestTitle = [latestDataDict objectForKey:@"title"];

        NSDictionary *existingDataDict = [self.arrNewsData objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *existingTitle = [existingDataDict objectForKey:@"title"];

        if ([latestTitle isEqualToString:existingTitle]) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);

            NSLog(@"No new data found.");
        }
        else{
            [self performNewFetchedDataActionsWithDataArray:dataArray];

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

            NSLog(@"New data was fetched.");
        }
    }
    else{
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);

        NSLog(@"Failed to fetch new data.");
    }
}];
}
...
#pragma mark IBActions
- (IBAction)reloadNews:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

> I've debugged the application and found that after viewDidLoad
>   completes execution, the data file is written but the view isn't
>   updated. I've also tried calling the *refreshData* method in the main
>   thread, but there's no change.
>   after viewDidLoad is complete the *showNoNewNews* method is called.

I'm suspecting that my logic isn't wrong but implementation is. Threads at play here..
Any help would be appreciated.

> **Update:**
>   Hope this helps those with similar problems...
>   I moved the logic of `viewDidLoad` to a different method, called the method for the first time in `viewDidLoad` and again in `refreshData`, after
>   `[self performNewFetchedDataActionsWithDataArray:dataArray];`

Comment: *never* call `viewDidLoad` yourself;  You need to call a function that does whatever is appropriate with the new data. You can then also call this function from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Use intermediate store and notifications. (i.e. CoreData store to cache data)

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 and Andy . I'm new to iOS and I appreciate your help and suggestions.